File opens with CRLF eol, despite of setting "files.eol": "\n" in settings.json
I've a TypeScript project on Windows 11 environment, which for some reason always opens file with line ending set as "CRLF", despite file endings being as "LF".
I've tried to force line endings from settings to "\n", with "files.eol": "\n", but  despite of that, files aways open with wrong line ending, and I have to change it manually from the bottom of editor.
Am I missing some location where this could been set otherwise, or does files have maybe some "metadata" that causes editor to open file incorrectly.
Forcing line endings in settings.json file to use "\n" endings ("files.eol": "\n"), this didn't help.
Also tried to create .code-workspace file for project, with content:
{
    "settings": {
        "files.eol": "\n",
        "editor.tabSize": 2,
        "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
            "source.fixAll": "explicit"
        },
          "eslint.validate": ["typescript"]
    }
}

and opening project with code project.code-workspace, but still when ever opening file, line endings are set as CRLF in editor.
